# What is the significance of Anton Ego's wine order?

Tags: ratatouille

When Ego is placing his order for "perspective" at Gusteau's, he requests:

> Very well. Since you're all out of perspective, and no one else seems to have it in this bloody town, I'll make you a deal. You provide the food; I'll provide the perspective. Which would go nicely with a bottle of *Cheval Blanc*, 1947.

Ego appears to be referring to [Château Cheval Blanc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ch%C3%A2teau_Cheval_Blanc). What is the significance of this particular wine, and the year? Would such a bottle be suitable for a randomly selected dish at a high-end restaurant, and for ratatouille in particular?

Comment: The wine goes with the **perspective** not the food.

Answer (score 6):

I don't think it's supposed to have any sort of significance other than Ego, well, stroking his ego. He's a very renowned food critic, the kind who can make or break a place, and pretty much every restaurant in town knows this. Older wine tends to be pricey, and this wine in particular has fetched a [very high price](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/finance/newsbysector/retailandconsumer/7589516/10-of-the-worlds-most-expensive-bottles-of-wine.html?image=7) from collectors, $135,125 for a single three liter bottle back in 2006 according to that link.

Ego's asking for a bottle of very expensive wine because he knows he'll get it, because if he doesn't he'll likely reflect upon that in his review.